# Question regarding Typescript version in SPFx

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling

I have few SPFx related queries as mentioned below.

- What is the current version of typescript in SPFx v1.71?
- if it is not the latest version then is there any plan to upgrade? It will be 
  great to know the timeline if there is any.
- If we have some external libraries with a dependency on latest version of
  typescript then is it possible to incorporate this new version in SPFx. If yes how?

Thanks,
Rajashekar

Answer (score 4):

**SPFx 1.7.1 relies on typescript 2.4.2**.
You can check that by creating a SPFx project and then run `npm list typescript`, look for the typescript entries bellow `@microsoft/sp-build-common`.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the info.. I am still looking for the answers to remaining two questions too.

Comment: The tooling of SPFx is locked down to this specific version of typescript and you should not upgrade typescript. For your external library, you should try to look for a version which is compatible with this version of typescript